# How to properly decode HTTP traffic

Tags: http, character-encoding, url-encoding, http-protocols

I'm looking at HTTP traffic, and seeing a POST request that is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with strange characters in it:

> t=%d8%94%b2%bc+%cb%ae%c9%ab

Various URL decodes that I tried running on this complain that it's not UTF-8 encoded.
I know that in theory a web request can be encoded in any given encoding scheme, but if so, how can I tell which scheme is being used (in order for me to decode it properly)?

I see no hint in the request itself.

This is not a language-specific question (more of a question about the HTTP protocol, I think.)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually contains the answer (form-urlencoded).  The request is URL encoded.  See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

The strange characters decode to non-ASCII characters except for the '+'.  There are decoders on the Web where you can cut and paste your text to see what it really is.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Ok, so I see that it's URL-encoded, but is it URL-encoded junk?  Or is it something in some language?  After URL decoding it, it fails UTF-8 decoding.  Is there a way to tell if it's UTF-8, or something else, or just random data that is URL-encoded?

I found this link that talks about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

I'm beginning to think that "%d8%94%b2%bc+%cb%ae%c9%ab" is just random URL-encoded junk...  But something inside me tells me that I'm just missing something....

Comment: It looks like random characters.  When you decode URL encoded characters, you get back decoded characters, not UTF-8 encoded characters (though they may look similar).  So UTF-8 decoding the result is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The link mentioned by Craig is correct. It decodes to Ø”²¼+Ë®É«